# Eclipse Java Code Assist is broken (Eclipse 2023-03, 4.27.0, MacOS, openjdk Java 17)

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I'm using JEE Eclipse 2023-03, Build id: 20230309-1520
with Java 17
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17+0)

I have a Java project working, but code-assist doesn't work.
I type a variable name, and none of the methods appear, just:
beg - Sets the cursor to the begin of the expression
cast...
and similarly for
constpriv, constpub, field, nnull, null, snnull, snull, var

Your help is appreciated.  FYI, my .project file is:

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>pc-vert</name>
    <comment>elided</comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

My settings for code assist are:
[image: here]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.
On the Content Assist Advanced page, the defaults were weird.
I'm not sure what was different, but I added some and it started working.  Then I hit Restore Defaults, and what I added was cleared, and it was still working...